# Invoke client event handler/listener when client connects to the event (adds itself to the event)

Tags: c#, events, hook

Is there a simple/clean/elegant way of having an event client be invoked at the time when it gets connected to an event? That is, when the client connects to the event using += such as:

```
someEvent += someClient
```

It would be useful if the client could be invoked 'right away' - as if the event had occurred just as the client is connecting. The purpose is to provide the client with the information from the most recent event that has occurred so the client can 'catch up' with the state associated with the event.

A concrete example: a store has some ticker-tape style signs in its windows. Each sign's code gets an event from the store's system telling it what to display (e.g., what's on sale at the moment). (Each sign displays the same thing.) When each sign gets turned on, it wants to know what the latest 'on sale' event was. If the store operator enters the sale info into the store system first (and the 'on sale' event goes out - to nobody), and then turns on the signs, the signs must somehow ask for the latest event's 'on sale' info. It seems cleaner to have the latest event (re)sent to a sign when it connects as an event client/receiver and thereby have just one mechanism in the sign.

Is there a way to connect a 'client has registered' hook to the event so that 'custom code' would be executed? In this case the code would send an event to (only) the new client so the client gets 'caught up'. For example, override the += operator used to register a client? (How to do so is not clear to me...)

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Test
{
    public delegate void TestEventHandler(int arg);
    private TestEventHandler _testEvent;
    private readonly _defaultEventArg = 42;

    public event TestEventHandler TestEvent
    {
        add
        {
            _testEvent += value;
            value(_defaultEventArg);
        }
        remove
        {
            _testEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}


var t = new Test();

t.TestEvent += (val) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event fired: " + val);
};
```

Comment: `public event TestEventHandler TestEvent;` can be `private TestEventHandler TestEvent;`. No need of two events. Other one can be just delegate.

Comment: Please add code to show how you would actually fire the event.

Comment: Also what I was driving at was to have the 'add' invoke _only_ the client being added (don't bother the clients that have hooked up in the past). So I'm believing I would invoke 'value(...args...)' in the 'add' rather than _testEvent().

Comment: @ArtSwri See updated answer. Now only the current handler being added is fired. The handler being added is fired by the `value();` line in `add`.

Comment: @ArtSwri I'm not sure what you would pass for an argument value if the event had arguments. You would need some sort of default values to pass I suppose.

Comment: @mclaassen Yes, I was planning on 'saving' the args from the most recently published event so that the 'catchup' call to value(...) would have the values available. These would be private fields like your _defaultEventArg (but not readonly, obviously).

Comment: @mclaassen I assume you are publishing the event like this: _testEvent(9876) -- or is there another way to send/publish(?)

Comment: @ArtSwri Yes, from the Test class that's how you would publish the event.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement custom event accessors.

Have a look at this [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb882534.aspx) from the MSDN.

I copied the snippet and inserted a comment where you can insert you code to call the newly added listener:

```
event EventHandler IDrawingObject.OnDraw
    {
        add
        {
            lock (PreDrawEvent)
            {
                // Write your custom code here
                PreDrawEvent += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (PreDrawEvent)
            {
                PreDrawEvent -= value;
            }
        }
    }
```